# Clojure matrix multiplication error: "Mismatched vector sizes" (clojure.core.matrix)

Tags: clojure, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix of size [1, 10] and another of size [1, 50] (they are both vectors - one will be transposed) which I want to multiply. I can do this in MATLAB but the [Clojure library](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) I am using returns an error indicating that the vector shapes are mismatched.

Here is the Clojure code (fails)

```
(def A [-0.4300 0.8205 0.3060 0.7011 0.3717 0.3790 0.6332 0.6179 0.5414 0.7277])
(m/shape A)
(def B [1 4.5239 1.0 4.54133 4.17334 1.0 2.3195 1.25481 2.57760 0.999 1.71030 1.167121 0.996 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.42060 4.53421 1.0 3.81672 2.26177 1.412147 1.13449 4.22844 1.87670 1.42931 4.13310 1.0 3.06024 1.0 0.999 1.02989 8.92018 8.90729 6.60117 2.61610 7.31420 1.0 4.23987 0.999 1.05592 5.31238 1.0 1.0 0.999 7.97549 1.6177 1.0 1.0])
(m/shape B)
(m/mmul (m/transpose A) B)
```

Equivalent operation in MATLAB:

```
A = [-0.4300 0.8205 0.3060 0.7011 0.3717 0.3790 0.6332 0.6179 0.5414 0.7277];
size(A)
B = [1 4.5239 1.0 4.54133 4.17334 1.0 2.3195 1.25481 2.57760 0.999 1.71030 1.167121 0.996 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.42060 4.53421 1.0 3.81672 2.26177 1.412147 1.13449 4.22844 1.87670 1.42931 4.13310 1.0 3.06024 1.0 0.999 1.02989 8.92018 8.90729 6.60117 2.61610 7.31420 1.0 4.23987 0.999 1.05592 5.31238 1.0 1.0 0.999 7.97549 1.6177 1.0 1.0];
size(B)
C = A' * B;
size(C)
```

Clearly the operation is mathematically possible - it should return a [10, 50] matrix... is there an error in the way I've implemented the calculation or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `mmul` documentation, the transposition is implicit in a vector depending on argument position:

> Performs matrix multiplication on matrices or vectors. Equivalent to
>   inner-product when applied to vectors.  Will treat a 1D vector roughly as a
>   1xN matrix (row vector) when it's the first argument, or as an Nx1 matrix
>   (column vector) when it's the second argument--except that the dimensionality
>   of the result will be different from what it would be with matrix arguments.

So, you should not transpose yourself.

Comment: Thank you. The documentation confused me because it says mmul treats a vector as a 1xN matrix, but I had to convert the vector to an actual matrix by enclosing it in square brackets, then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
(let [A [[-0.4300 0.8205 0.3060 0.7011 0.3717 0.3790 0.6332 0.6179 0.5414 0.7277]]
      B [[1 4.5239 1.0 4.54133 4.17334 1.0 2.3195 1.25481 2.57760 0.999 1.71030 1.167121 0.996 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.42060 4.53421 1.0 3.81672 2.26177 1.412147 1.13449 4.22844 1.87670 1.42931 4.13310 1.0 3.06024 1.0 0.999 1.02989 8.92018 8.90729 6.60117 2.61610 7.31420 1.0 4.23987 0.999 1.05592 5.31238 1.0 1.0 0.999 7.97549 1.6177 1.0 1.0]]]
    (mmul (transpose A) B))
```

`[2 3 5]` is not a matrix but a vector.

`[[2 3 5]]` is a matrix.

Comment: Wrapping the vector in brackets solved the problem. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but thanks for the answer. I accepted the other because it highlighted the source of the problem as well. Thanks though.